# input type=date is not working in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date.startingDate" id="startingDate">
```

this is the code to pick date from date picker in ionic.after setting the date in date picker it type only 2015-0. and app carshs.

Comment: Have you tried it with closing the tag, like `<input type="date" ng-model="something" />`

Answer (score 0):

**Try thIs:**

```
 <ion-input id="input-date" type="date" mode="md" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"> </ion-input>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<input style="width:100%" class="textbox-n" type="date"  id="startingDate" name="startingDate" ng-model="date.startingDate" />
```